# Converting between classes representing the same thing in different libraries

Tags: design-patterns, software-design, data-conversion, converters

I’m working on a project which uses many independent libraries, so they are not somehow connected at all. For example imagine having a simple physics library, and a 2D renderer. Both of those use their own implementation of a Vector2D class. I would like to use instances of the Vector2D class generated by the physics library to work with the renderer. The problem is the classes, despite representing the same thing, are incompactible, in fact they are 2 different classes not knowing anything about each other. I do know how to convert a Vector2D produced by the physics system to a Vector2D class which the renderer uses - you just need to get the values (X, Y) and create a new instance of the other class. What I’m looking for is a more sophisticated solution, ideally a design pattern which solves this while keeping the code clean. I have seen the adapter design pattern, but it’s unnecesarily too complicated and it should be a one-time conversion.

Comment: Should not be possible for third party classes, and byte code manipulation -.class altering code - implementing conversion interfaces is ridiculous as a shoe with a long curly nose. Source code translators, converters, are the only clean solution. Going for immutable classes, `record` and such. I hope this rant makes some sense.

Comment: "I would like to use instances of the Vector2D class generated by the physics library to work with the renderer" - what do you mean by "work with"? There are plenty of design patterns, and choosing the right one depends on your use case which you haven't described

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.